# How get native image size at runtime?

Tags: c#

I need to scale the plane with the height and width of the image, so the maintexture of the plane will not stretch.
like this:

```
    void LoadBG()
{
    string bgpaht = Application.persistentDataPath +"/a.png";
    if (File.Exists(bgpath))
    {
        byte[] bgbyte=File.ReadAllBytes(bgpath);
        ...
        ...
        Texture2D t2d = new Texture2D(a.width,a.height); 
        t2d.LoadImage(bgbyte);
        plane.transform.localScale = new Vector3(t2d.width,1.0f,t2d.height);
        plane.renderer.material.mainTexture=t2d;

    }
}
```

OK,now how  can I  get the width and height of the image "a.png"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the `Image` class?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Image(v=vs.110).aspx

It has the properties `Height` and `Width`.

Just load the image like this

```
Image yourImage = Image.FromFile(pathOfYourFile);
```

Comment: I agree with you ,but I want to realize it at IOS,so I can not find the suitable  "System.Drawing.dll"

Comment: my god,I was so careless,the answer "http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html"